# is linux/compiler.h a userspace header?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, gentoo, linux-kernel, header-file

VirtualBox is looking for this file in `/usr/include` but it's missing in gentoo linux-headers

Does someone know if that is userspace header and gentoo is missing it? Or if that is not it, then if virtualbox is doing it wrong?

actual bug: https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408611#c6

```
In file included from /var/tmp/portage/x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox-4.1.10/work/VirtualBox-4.1.10/include/iprt/mem.h:31:0,
                 from /var/tmp/portage/x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox-4.1.10/work/VirtualBox-4.1.10/src/VBox/Runtime/common/alloc/alloc.cpp:34:
/var/tmp/portage/x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox-4.1.10/work/VirtualBox-4.1.10/include/iprt/types.h:112:30: fatal error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.


Reproducible: Always
```

also tested with kernel 3.6.6, 3.7-rc5 and some other, on virtualbox 4.2.0 4.2.2 4.2.4

Comment: It's a kernel header that doesn't get installed to /usr/include. Can't repro with 3.6.6 or 3.3.4 (configured and prepared) and VirtualBox 4.2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is not part of the Linux user space API, so it does not get installed into /usr/include.

If VirtualBox wants to compile its own kernel extensions, it should add the kernel *source* include directory to its include path.
(That would be `/lib/`*version*`/modules/build/include/`.)

Comment: Ok, I need to review why does it does not